# Jasmine test runner integration with visual studio and a build process

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, jasmine

how do you integrate Jasmine's test runner with Visual Studio and your custom build process ? I've read an article at codebetter that shows how to achieve this task using FubuMVC and a few other components but I was wondering if you can recommend any alternatives ?

So how do you do that at your workplace ?

Many thanks,
Tomek

Comment: When you say you want to integrate with Visual Studio, do you mean using Visual Studio built-in test runner or using any test runner is fine ?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Chutzpah (http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/). It has integrated test runners and command line options for running Jasmine or QUnit tests. Behind the scenes it uses PhantomJS, a headless browser, to load up tests and run them.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a year old, but FYI, I noticed that a new AngularJS SPA Template project (ASP.NET) in Visual Studio 2013 includes Jasmine (SpecRunner.cshtml).  The AngularJS SPA Template is an extension to VS2013 (and can be installed on VS2012 and VS2010).
So it is there now, go to extensions and updates in VS to find it!